# Docker container closes after starting Apache

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

OK, So I've set up my docker container as I need it.

This is my current *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential sudo software-properties-common \
    libboost-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev \
    libboost-regex-dev libboost-system-dev libboost-thread-dev \
    libicu-dev libtiff5-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng12-dev \
    libxml2-dev libproj-dev libsqlite3-dev libgdal-dev \
    libcairo-dev libharfbuzz-dev

RUN apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs 

RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev python-dev git python-pip \
    python-setuptools python-wheel python3-setuptools \
    python3-pip python3-wheel python-cairo-dev libboost-python-dev

RUN apt-get install -y ruby ruby-dev

RUN apt-get install -y wget curl 

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install mapnik

RUN sudo gem install awesome_print colorize twitter_cldr \
    nokogiri unidecoder

RUN apt-get -y install apache2 php-pear lynx-cur

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

EXPOSE 80

ADD apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

If I build it and run it with `docker run -p 80:80 -it mycontainer`, it runs fine. I can go via the terminal, do a `/usr/bin/apache2ctl start`, the server starts as usual and I can access it via *localhost* from my host's browser. Great!

Now, the idea is to simply put that `/usr/bin/apache2ctl start` command inside my *Dockerfile*, so that I don't have to write it every time the container starts.

**However:** if I put `CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "start"]` at the very end of my *Dockerfile*, build it and run it (with `docker run -p 80:80 -it mycontainer`), the container seems to start, outputs an Apache message and then it stops, no terminal, nothing. (nor does it run in the background).

What goes on? I just want to be able to start Apache automatically and keep the terminal live, so that I can do things there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Containers are a tool to isolate a running application, and they run until the application that was launched exits. If this application is a shell or command that launches a daemon in the background like you've done, when the shell or command returns, the container will promptly exit.

The solution is to run your application in the foreground. The steps to do this with Apache have already been done with the official images which I'd recommend using over building your own. You can [see their Dockerfile here](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/tree/3af22f20b54cbb7c76ef4c3b12bd9dcf6cae862b/2.4). And you can [use their image on Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/).

Comment: This is exactly right. You're looking for `apachectl -D FOREGROUND`

Comment: @brandon-barnett your solution is very nice thanks a lot !